# draw2d javascript library - multiline label

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw2d-js

Do you have an idea how to create a multiline label with draw2d's `draw2d.shape.basic.Label`

Comment: fwiw, [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) has support for multiline text out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This library is using the [HTML5 Canvas API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). In order to draw text it is using the [`fillText()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp) method which does not have multi-line support out of the box. In order to achieve such the text needs to be broken down into multiple labels, which I don't think this library has support for.

Comment: is it using Canvas API? From what I know, it uses SVG/VML, since it is based on Raphael. And, as @alexander-stefanov says, it can be done programatically, I've actually tried that - it inserts two `<tspan>` elements in the `<svg>`

Comment: What do you mean by "it can be done programatically". Can you please post an example? How can I "break it down into multiple labels"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make a multiline label (at least visually) by setting label's text programatically with '\n' in it. Like `label.setText('Some \n text')`. But you can't do it 'manually', since you're typing in an `<input type="text">`